# Django api call in view to save foreign key of user model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What i am doing is django 2 project call api to django 1 project to book an appointment in `Appointment` table and save the details into `BookAppt` table.

After updating my code based on one of the answer given, i got this error now. `{"patientId":["This field is required."]}` I have no idea why even though i did include it in already.

Please help as i have been stuck at this part for 2 days now.

**Do note that it is django 2 calling to django 1. Here is my code:**

**- model.py**

**-- django 1**

```
class Appointments (models.Model):
    patientId = models.IntegerField()
    clinicId = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticketNo = models.IntegerField()

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("Booked", "Booked"),
        ("Done", "Done"),
        ("Cancelled", "Cancelled"),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Booked")
```

**-- django 2**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class BookAppt(models.Model):
    clinicId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    patientId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scheduleTime = models.DateTimeField()
    ticketNo = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**- serializer**

**-- django 1**

```
class AppointmentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Appointments
        fields = ('id', 'patientId', 'clinicId', 'date', 'time', 'created', 'ticketNo', 'status')
```

**-- django 2**

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('userId', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'nric', 'birthday', 'birthTime')
        read_only_fields = ('userId',)


class BookApptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    patientId = MyUserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = BookAppt
        fields = ('id', 'patientId', 'clinicId', 'scheduleTime', 'ticketNo', 'status')
```

**- view.py**

**-- django 1**

```
class AppointmentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Appointments.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentsSerializer
```

**-- django 2**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        patient = request.data['patientId']
        patientId = MyUser.objects.get(id=patient)

        saveget_attrs = {
            "patientId": patientId,
            "clinicId": data["clinicId"],
            "scheduleTime": data["created"],
            "ticketNo": data["ticketNo"],
            "status": data["status"],
        }
        saving = BookAppt.objects.create(**saveget_attrs)

        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse(r.text)


class BookApptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = BookAppt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookApptSerializer
```

**-Update 1**

**serializer**

```
class BookApptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    patientId = MyUserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = BookAppt
        fields = ('id', 'patientId', 'clinicId', 'scheduleTime', 'ticketNo', 'status')
```

**Error**

`'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues you have a problem in a `BookApptSerializer`. Remove a `MyUserSerializer` from `patientId` field and use default one. It will accept id string or number. If you want to display user data, you can override `to_representation` method or use `MethodField`.

```
class BookApptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BookAppt
        fields = ('id', 'patientId', 'clinicId', 'scheduleTime', 'ticketNo', 'status')
```

Comment: I did try that before, I end up getting another error. This : `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`. This is probably cause in this line of django 2 views `patient = request.data['patientId']`. But i still don't get what was the problem.

Comment: @JinNiiSama which version of DRF you use? maybe it is an old version with `DATA` and `FILES` properties instead of single `data` or maybe you forgot to install DRF at all :) . Anyway you can check the available methods by `dir(request)`. What is `request.POST` showing?

Comment: My current version is 1.11.3, the reason why i didn't update is because if i did, my code would need to change since if im not wrong, in url.py, its using path instead of url. I am not really sure if the update will mess up my entire project.

Comment: I insert the `print(data)` just after `data=r.json()`. This is the post value. `[31/Jan/2018 10:21:42] "POST /api/makeapp/ HTTP/1.1" 201 139
{'id': 22, 'patientId': 4, 'clinicId': '1', 'date': '2018-07-10', 'time': '08:00 AM', 'created': '2018-01-31 01:21:42', 'ticketNo': 1, 'status': 'Booked'}`

Comment: @JinNiiSama ok then use this data instead of `request.data['patientId']` you already have all data in line `data=r.json()`, older versions of DRF doesn't have `.data` property

Comment: @JinNiiSama did you try solution from my previous comment?

Comment: doing that will give the `ValueError: Cannot assign "4": "BookAppt.patientId" must be a "MyUser" instance.` So i use `patient = request.data['patientId']` and it works now. Thank you